# Execute sql queries gcloud command line

Tags: google-cloud-platform, sql-insert, google-cloud-sql

I have a SQL instance which has a DB into which I will be importing some data using `gcloud sql import ...`.

Thereafter, I want to run a list of `INSERT` queries to insert data into tables in that DB.

However, I am not able to find a nice way to do this via the command line as something that can potentially be automated via a script - something like, `gcloud sql execute <query>` or equivalent - and it seems like the only way to do it is by connecting to the the instance (via `gcloud sql connect` or sql proxy) and manually executing each `INSERT` query in the interactive SQL CLI.

Does anybody know if there is a better way to do this? I'm not clear on whether or not `gcloud` supports this type of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

By the moment gcloud sql is only used for create and manage instances on Cloud SQL [1], as you mentioned the only way for execute queries or scripts is throught gcloud sql connect.

You can create a feature request for this task through issue tracker [2].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/sql
[2] https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker